# How to interface ethernet with STM32 Microcontroller?

Tags: networking, ethernet, stm32f4, switching, ethernet-phy

The project uses an ethernet loop which is connected through the STM32 Microcontroller. I have to use ethernet switch IC(4 port). What are the topics that I have to know so that I can use the ethernet in the project? Also how to interface the ethernet switch IC, transceiver with the MCU? How to read and transfer data (integer data) through the ethernet.

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter what you want to send over ethernet and how many ports your switch has. You need to know what protocol your other devices use. At the moment you most of them use TCP/IP and you need to implement it in your app. CubeMX has support for LWIP stack.

You can also use external chips with built in TCP/IP stack like Wiznet W5100, 55000 or other chips.

> How to read and transfer data (integer data) through the ethernet.

You will need to read about TCP, UDP, ports, sockets etc. It a too wide topic to be answered in the forum post

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. As far I understood till now, this is the flow

"Cable from ISP --> Router --> Switch --> Transceiver (Ethernet PHY - W500....) --> Microcontroller"

Comment: the most difficult part is TCP/IP stack not the cables

Comment: Agreed. I am in the initial stage of the project, as a block-level flow I was referring that. If it is correct then I can break the blocks further and can proceed further with the TCP/IP stack and other concepts. And I don't have much knowledge on the Ethernet. In this project only I came to know about switch, Ethernet PHY, OSI layer and each layer's functionalities. Proceeding further I have to work on the firmware and stack part of the ethernet.